# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

### Bug Report

```
[Nest] 14964  - 08/24/2023, 12:15:56 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
    at CategoryService.createOne (\node_modules\@nestjsx\crud-typeorm\src\typeorm-crud.service.ts:118:35)
    at CategoryController.createOneBase (\node_modules\@nestjsx\crud\src\crud\crud-routes.factory.ts:227:27)
    at \node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

### Current behavior

I use to create a new Category. Here is describing it in json:

```json
{
  "name": "New Category"
}
```

### Input Code

> Entity

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';

import { Product } from './product.entity';

@Entity('category')
export class Category {
  @Column({ name: 'id', type: 'bigint' })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'name', nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at', type: 'timestamp' })
  CreatedAt: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at', type: 'timestamp' })
  UpdatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ name: 'deleted_at', nullable: true })
  DeletedAt?: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.category)
  products: Product[];
}
```

> Controller

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Crud, CrudController } from '@nestjsx/crud';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';

import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { CreateCategoryDto, UpdateCategoryDto } from './dto/category.dto';

import { Category } from '../../database/entity/category.entity';

@ApiTags('category')
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Category,
  },
  dto: {
    create: CreateCategoryDto,
    update: UpdateCategoryDto,
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      products: {
        eager: true,
      },
    },
  },
  routes: {
    only: [
      'getManyBase',
      'getOneBase',
      'createOneBase',
      'updateOneBase',
      'deleteOneBase',
    ],
  },
})
@Controller('category')
export class CategoryController implements CrudController<Category> {
  constructor(public service: CategoryService) {}
}
```

> Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmCrudService } from '@nestjsx/crud-typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { Category } from '../../database/entity/category.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService extends TypeOrmCrudService<Category> {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Category) repository: Repository<Category>) {
    super(repository);
  }
}
```

> Module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { CategoryController } from './category.controller';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';

import { Category } from '../../database/entity/category.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Category])],
  controllers: [CategoryController],
  providers: [CategoryService],
})
export class CategoryModule {}
```

> DTO

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateCategoryDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;
}

export class UpdateCategoryDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  name?: string;
}
```

### Expected behavior

I expected it to create a new category with the corresponding name!

### Environment

```
Package version: 0.0.1

 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v18.16.0
- Platform:  Windows
- Database: Postgres

Other:
- "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0"
- "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0"
- "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0"
- "pg": "^8.11.2"
- "@nestjsx/crud": "^5.0.0-alpha.3"
- "@nestjsx/crud-typeorm": "^5.0.0-alpha.3"
```

### Current behavior

I use to create a new Category. Here is describing it in json:

```json
{
  "name": "New Category"
}
```

### Expected behavior

I expected it to create a new category with the corresponding name!

Comment: Can you downgrade your `@nestjsx/*` dependencies to `v4.6.2`, which is the latest stable release (rather than the alpha release you are using)?

Comment: @RobinThomas I have downgraded ver like you said but it's still the same error! I see in my package.json is nestjs ver 10. While, nestjsx's package.json is using nestjs ver 9. [link](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: I was right, I downgraded nestjs ver and it's accessible. Thank you❤
```package.json
     "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
     "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
     "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.0",
     "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
```

Comment: Everything is ok, do you want to answer something to let me understand more? Go ahead and say it, I'll listen

Answer (score 2):

### **Error has been successfully fixed!**

I downgraded nestjs ver and it's accessible.

```
     "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
     "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
     "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.0",
     "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
```